# Question about simple extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am studying abstract algebra with fraleigh and I'm in extension field part now. But I don't understand why element in extension field can be expressed as a quotient of polynomials. Lots of problems use it to prove some properties but they don't explain how it holds. Please give me details about this technique, thank you.

Comment: You have to look carefuly at the field of rational functions $\Bbb{C}(X)$, the field of fractions of the ring of polynomials  $\Bbb{C}[X]$,.then at $\Bbb{C=R(i)=R[x]/(x^2+1)}$, this time no need of field of fractions because the inverses are polynomials in $i$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still don't understand. I think simple extension field F(b) is image of evaluation homomorphism on field F. So, it is okay to be expressed as a polynomials of b. However, why is it okay to be expressed as a quotient of polynomials of b?